# Get last rows based on datetime and using name

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following table in MYSQL:

```
DATETIME dt
VARCHAR location
FLOAT temperature
```

This table contains many temperatures measured at different locations. Now I need a SQL query to get the last measurements done for each location.

I actually have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that while doing group by aggregate its better to have the column selected prior doing group by.

```
select
t1.location,
t2.t2_dt as dt,
t1.temperature 
from table_name t1 
join
(
  select
  location,
  temperature,
  max(dt) as t2_dt
  from table_name
  group by location
)t2
on t2.location = t1.location AND t1.dt = t2.t2_dt
group by t1.location
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e56ea/4)**

Answer (score 1):

This will do your job

```
    select * from
    (select location, temperature, dt from my_table) as tab
    join
    (select max(dt) as max_dt from my_table
    group by location) as max_date_tab
    on (tab.dt = max_date_tab.max_dt)
```